# Huge spikes in training curve with TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

Below is my training curve using TensorFlow 1.9:

[image]

**What could be causing these spikes in the training loss?**

Some details:

- The network has 5 layers, takes in an image, and predicts a 4-dimensional vector.
- Training is done using minibatches of size 50.
- For each epoch, my entire dataset is iterated. Therefore, the spikes are not due to randomly sampling a "difficult" minibatch.
- I am using the Adam optimiser, with TensorFlow's default parameters, and a learning rate of 0.001.
- The output (and input) data are normalised to have zero mean and standard deviation of 1.
- I have checked the points at which these spikes occur, and rather than a single training example having a high loss, often there are a few training examples within a single minibatch with have a (very) high loss.

As an example, the predictions made by the network for two these examples are: 
`[ 33.939026 -69.096344  75.832924  35.009373]`
and
`[ -87.652336   52.033615  -94.49006  -168.82799 ]`, where the labels for these examples are both:
`[ 2.041661e-02 -4.019599e-01 -1.813140e-04  1.500889e-01]`. So this leads to a loss of 3209 and 479, respectively.

For examples where the loss is "normal", a typical prediction is:
`[ 2.041661e-02 -4.019650e-01 -1.770628e-04  1.500889e-01]`
with a label of:
`[-1.135244 -0.091564  0.46258  -0.078056]`.

So it seems that all of a sudden, the predictions made for a few training examples have a huge magnitude, and then this magnitude very quickly dies down to a more acceptable level.

Any ideas on what is causing this, or how I might debug it?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to your problem?